# Fading background image slider with css: How can I make the slides stay on screen longer?

Tags: html, css

My objective is to make the images stay on screen for about 10 seconds - without increasing the fade duration (if possible). I have tried messing with the keyframe percentages, but I just cant seem to get it right. Any help would be much appreciated.

```css
.slider {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.slide1,.slide2,.slide3,.slide4,.slide5 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slide1 {
  background: url(http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946/580x0-9_cropped_1371566801_p17tbs0rrjqdt1u4dnk94fe4b63.jpg)no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
    animation:fade 30s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade 30s infinite;

} 
.slide2 {
  background: url(http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946/580x0-9_cropped_1371565525_p17tbqpu0d69c21hetd77dh483.jpeg)no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
    animation:fade2 30s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade2 30s infinite;
}
.slide3 {
    background: url(http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946/580x0-9_cropped_1371564896_p17tbq6n86jdo3ishhta3fv1i3.jpg)no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
    animation:fade3 30s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade3 30s infinite;
}
@keyframes fade {
    0%,
    27% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    33.333% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    66.666% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

@keyframes fade2 {
    0% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    33.333%,
    60% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    66.666% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}

@keyframes fade3 {
    0% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    33.333% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    66.666%,
    93% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}
```

```html
<div class='slider'>
  <div class='slide1'></div>
  <div class='slide2'></div>
  <div class='slide3'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can set the animation rules on `.slider*`, use the same fade animation and then use `animation-delay` to delay the animation by 30s. More about `animation-delay` at this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-webkit-animation-delay: 50s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
animation-delay: 50s;
```

check: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4zbx0cod/)

Comment: if I add that to slider, it has no effect. If I add that to slide1 slide2 slide3, there is a delay added before the first image begins to fade, but then the images fade as normal with no delay between them.

Comment: Please check the updated answer now and the jsFiddle! And let me know if its alright!